# Wrong numbers in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to enter my XP in mysql. Now is the xp with a , so i removed them with a small script. Now i want to enter them in mysql and this is what i get : Overallxpnow = 8388607

Now the problem is my xp is  328,147,065. So it's is not right. I entered a echo with the variable that is used to get it in mysql and it shows the 328 xp amount (the correct one). The problem is that i really have no idea why it is showing me the wrong number.

This is the script :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM track WHERE  `rsname` ='$name'");

if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE  track SET 
    `rsname` = '$name',
    `overallranknow` = '$Overalln', 
    `overalllevelnow` = '$Overall[1]',
    `overallxp` = '$Overalln2' WHERE 
    `rsname` = '$name', 
    `overallranknow` = '$Overalln', 
    `overalllevelnow` = '$Overall[1]'
    `overallxpnow` = '$Overall2'");
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO track (`rsname`, `overallranknow`, `overalllevelnow`, `overallxpnow` ) VALUES ('$name', '$Overalln', '$Overall[1]', '$Overall2')");

}   
}
```

This is the code to remove the ,

```
$value2= $Overall[2]; 
$bad_symbols2 = array(",", "."); 
$Overall2 = str_replace($bad_symbols2, "", $value2);
```

I hope i told as mutch info as i can.

Also i'm using mediumint as tabel type.

~Kev (bad english = sorry)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Use a larger data type. [`MEDIUMINT: minimum value: -8388608, maximum value: 8388607`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: @DCoder Thanks got it working now! changed to a bigint Also i did not now that about the mysql_*. Because that's what i always use.

Comment: When I have a problem with limiting to a number, I put the number in google, it always shows an article where says it's maximum for something, if it is.

Comment: @Kev30: Now you know. Seriously, stop using it. It *will* bit you back in the ass sooner or later.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Will do it ASAP! and royal bg thanks for the tip.

Comment: Assuming that XP can only be positive it might be worth changing it from a signed to an unsigned field as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong field type. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) says `MEDIUMINT` has a range of -8388608 to 8388607.

Comment: +1 This is what happens when you go cheap on datatypes :) *Know thy datatypes and their sizes, only then can you make informed DB design decisions.*